# setBackgroundColor is getting ignored

Tags: java, android, android-handler, thread-sleep

```
   layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1250);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I want to change the BackgroundColor of my Layout to green at first and after waiting for 1.25 sec it should turn blue. 
The BackgroundColor changes to blue after 1.25 sec but does not turn Green before. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are putting main thread (UI thread) on sleep which is causing the issue.

Try this

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}, 1250);
```

Make sure `layout` is declared as final.

Answer (score 0):

You have just changed your background color twice above. So it's considered your last **BLUE** color only.

you have to do something like this.

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

 Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override 
         public void run() { 
              layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
         } 
    }, 1250);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Handler like this:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 Handler h=new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
        },1250);
```

**Never, do Thread.sleep() on a UI thread**.

That is what is causing the problem initially.

you could use this to sleep eg. background thread.

This Handler solution has two **advantages**:

(1) avoids system overhead of 2nd thread,

(2) runs on UI thread, so can make UI changes without causing an exception.